# Getting information from a rails class instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails so I'm sure this is really simple, but here is my thing.

I get `request` like this:

```
request = Request.where(id: params[:id_request])
```

So I logged this in console and it's returning what I want, but how do I access some fields of that?

I tried this:

```
request.required_people
```

This don't work obviously, but how do I get `required_people` from `request`?

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider a different model name than `Request` as Rails controllers have the `request` method which may cause confusion should you ever need to access it in a controller or helper method.  Also, the convention for params is more common to usa a naming convention of `request_id` vs `id_request`.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Thanks for the tips. I'll probably change the name then. For `request_id` I know, I've seen it too late but I'm going to change that later, the whole app is based on it right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `where`, you're returning a collection of items rather than an individual record, even if that where query only returns one result. As this collection is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` we can call `.first` to get the first item in the collection:

```
request.first.required_people
```

But since you are looking for a single record you can just use `.find` which takes the model's primary key `id` as it's argument:

```
request = Request.find(params[:id_request])
```

That will let you do

```
request.required_people
```

If you really want to see the difference, try doing both the where and the find query. You'll see the where query has a few extra brackets on the return value.